# How to define sequelize relationship without actual foreign key?

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, object-relational-model

I have an existing database like this:

```
students:
  name        : string
  school_id   : integer

schools:
  name        : string
```

school_id attribute on students table **is not** an actual foreign key. It's just an integer represents the relationship between the students and the schools without any foreign key.

With this kind of design, how can I define the relationship on sequelize so I can get the school name of a student (student.school.name)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'not an actual foreign key'. Do you mean that you don't want `FOREIGN KEY ... REFERENCES ...` in your table definition? Does school and student not have an id column?